# Regular expressions are stripped off '\' when given as command line argument to python script

Tags: python, regex, command-line

I am writing a scripts that needs regular expressions to be specified on the command line. So program should be able to take `\d+` at command line like:

```
python3 my_script.py \d+
```

Suppose my_script.py searches some file(s) based on the regular expression given on command line.

But when I do this, the leading `\` are stripped off. So printing  `sys.argv` has `['my_script.py', 'd+']`.

How can I have the regular expression specified on command line to be taken as it is? Please see that regular expression are not in quotes. Is it even possible?

(I am using **getopt module** to process my input arguments)

Comment: "Please see that regular expression are not in quotes" - well, why not? You need to wrap it in single-quotes to stop the shell from pre-processing it.

Comment: Well  it was the requirement that the regular expression be specified as in grep. And grep does not take it in quotes. Though the character classes are specified differently.

Comment: Try to grep for the regex `a*` in a directory with files whose names start with `a`, and you'll be unpleasantly surprised. Shell preprocessing works the same for grep as it does for any other program. You can only leave the quotes off if there isn't anything in your regex that the shell will mess with.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should probably use two backslashes:

```
python3 my_script.py \\d+
```

or

```
python3 my_script.py '\d+'
```

To have a backslash in a string literal get read properly, it needs to be either escaped or quoted.

Comment: Command line shell "eats" the backslash character, as it wants to interpret the escape code (C style).

Comment: @Thawn: No it doesn't. You're mixing up the string's `repr` representation with the string's actual contents.

Comment: @schwobaseggl @Peter. Thanks this solution works. But I mean to ask that if I pass any regular expression like `\\d{10,20}`, then it would break it up like ['my_script.py', '\\d10', '\\d20']. Why does it behave this way?

Comment: @mkike yes, probably the version with quotes is more flexible.

Comment: Thanks. Probably I will do it. Waiting if someone ever did something like this. :)

Comment: When passing around strings that will be used for regexes, my first bugfix attempt is always to try double and quadruple backslashes :D